# CSS display:flex equal parts

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why the flexbox that I created isn't dividing the three child divs (image, content & action) into equal sizes vertically?
The plunk is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zqdpqnV7QkKrx7lm1Tsi?p=preview

CSS:

```
    .card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem #aaa;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card.sm {
  height: 10rem;
}

.card.sm .card-action {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.card.md {
  height: 20rem;
}

.card.md .card-action {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card.lg {
  height: 30rem;
}

.card.lg .card-action {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card .card-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.card .card-action {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card .card-image {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.card .card-image img {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:30rem">
    <div class="card md">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8fe/sky-above-the-black-mountains-1402912.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Title</span>
        <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `flex-basis: auto` instead of `0`.

You may also need to use `min-height: 0` or `overflow` different than visible to force same size even if the contents are taller.

```css
.card > * {
  flex: 1;        /* Same height ... */
  overflow: auto; /* ... even if the content is taller */
}
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card > * {
  flex: 1;        /* Same height ... */
  overflow: auto; /* ... even if the content is to tall */
}
.card.md .card-action {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .card-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.card .card-image img {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:30rem">
  <div class="card md">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8fe/sky-above-the-black-mountains-1402912.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">Title</span>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, note that since you have paddings, the heights might still be a bit different. You may remove them and place them in an inner container instead. Or something like this:

```css
.card > * {
  flex: 1 2rem; /* Set flex-basis to the maximum paddings among flex items */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card > * {
  flex: 1 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card.md .card-action {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .card-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.card .card-image img {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:30rem">
  <div class="card md">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8fe/sky-above-the-black-mountains-1402912.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">Title</span>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }
```